# Expectation of a martingale

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales

I have a stochastic variable $Z$ and know that that $Z(t)/Z(0)$ is a martingale. Now, my book claims that this means that it has mean 1. I assume this is because of the martingale-property:

$$
E[Z(t)/Z(0)] = Z(0)/Z(0) = 1
$$

However, the above I guess only makes sense if we take the expectation value up to and include time $0$. But I would think that when we refer to the mean of a variable, then we are taking the expectation up to infinity, and not 0?

Comment: $Z:(\omega,t)\mapsto Z(\omega,t)$ is a function of two variables: $\omega$ (from our probability space) and $t$ (from our time space). When we write $\mathbb{E}Z(t)$ what we implicitely mean is $\int_\Omega Z(\omega,t)P(d\omega)$. I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "up to infinity." Maybe the following example will clarify things: if $Z(t)$ has a density $f$ and support $[0,+\infty)$ the previous discussion simply means $\mathbb{E}Z(t)=\int_0^\infty xf(x)dx$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @charlus said, for every $t \in \mathbb R^+$, $Z(t)$ is a **random variable**. So when we take the expectation $\mathbb E[Z(t)]$, we integrate with respect to $\omega$ and not $t$. In other words, $$\mathbb E[Z(t)] := \int_{\omega \in \Omega} Z(t,\omega) d\mathbb P(\omega) \quad \forall t\in\mathbb R^+ $$
So there isn't any notion of "taking expectation up to infinity", we are simply computing the expectation of every random variable $Z(t)$ in the family $\{Z(t),t\in\mathbb R^+\}$.

As for the result you want to prove, it is indeed a consequence of the martingale property :
I assume that $Z(0)$ is a constant almost surely, and that you are working with the canonical filtration $(\mathcal F_t)_{t\ge0}$ for which the process $Z(t)/Z(0)$ is a martingale.
The martingale property tells you that for every $s\le t$, $\mathbb E[Z(t)/Z(0)\ |\ \mathcal F_s] = Z(s)/Z(0)$

Now noticing that $\mathcal F_0 = \{\varnothing, \Omega\}$, what your book says is that

$$\begin{align}\mathbb E[Z(t)/Z(0)] &= \mathbb E [Z(t)/Z(0)\  |\ \Omega] \\
&=\mathbb E [Z(t)/Z(0) \ |\ \mathcal F_0] \\
&= Z(0) / Z(0) \ \text{ by the martingale property} \\
&= 1 \end{align} $$

**Edit :**
As suggested by @Brian Moehring I'll do the proof without the assumption of almost surely constant $Z(0)$, which is unnecessary. So now we just assume that $Z(0) \ne 0$ almost surely :
$$\begin{align}\mathbb E[Z(t)/Z(0)] &= \mathbb E[\mathbb E [Z(t)/Z(0)\  |\ \mathcal F_0]] \text{ (law of total expectation)} \\
&=\mathbb E [Z(0)/Z(0)] \text{ by the martingale property}  \\
&= 1 \end{align} $$

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can you add some explanation to why $\mathbb E[Z(t)/Z(0)] = \mathbb E [Z(t)/Z(0)\  |\ \mathcal F_0]$ holds? I don't get that.

Comment: Related to my comment above, I guess another question is what $\Omega$ is more specifically? Thanks in advance.

Comment: No problem ! Careful, there is an extra $\mathbb E$ sign. What I used is the [law of total expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation) that says that, in a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal F, \mathbb P)$, for any sub-sigma algebra $\mathcal G \subseteq \mathcal F$, and any random variable $X$ on that probability space, it holds that $\mathbb E [ \mathbb E [ X |\mathcal G]] = \mathbb E[X]$. Saying it in words : "the expectation of the conditional expectation is equal to the expectation". For your second question, $\Omega$ is just the usual space of possible outcomes.

Comment: Thanks. Just to be clear: If $\Omega$ is the usual space of possible outcomes, then how can $\mathcal{F}_0$ be equal to it? I mean, $\mathcal{F}_0$ is only the information contained up to and including $t\leq 0$ - that is hardly "all possible outcomes" (?)

Comment: Also: If I use the law of total expectation, then I guess I can also write $\mathbb E[Z(t)/Z(0)] = \mathbb E[\mathbb E [Z(t)/Z(0)\  |\ \mathcal F_s]] = \mathbb E [Z(s)/Z(0)]$ for some $s<t$? This just to test my understanding.

Comment: Let's denote the process $X_t := Z(t)/Z(0)$. If $X_0$ is almost surely constant, then $\mathcal F_0 = \sigma (X_0) = \{\varnothing, \Omega\}$. Your process is not defined for negative times so really the only information you have is the realization at time $t=0$ which is only the trivial sigma-algebra since $X_0$ is constant. One last thing, $\mathcal F_0$ is a sigma-algebra so it can't be equal to $\Omega$ which is an event. I just used the fact that $\mathbb E[X|\Omega] = \mathbb E[X|\{\Omega, \varnothing\}]$

Comment: Yes, what you've written is correct